# Drag and Drop rows in an ASP.NET gridview using jQuery

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview, drag-and-drop, tablednd

I am having trouble implementing the drag and drop facility in my ASP.NET gridview using jQuery. I tried using the Drag and Drop plugin provided by http://isocra.com/2008/02/table-drag-and-drop-jquery-plugin/, but it doesnt quite work with my grids, I am referencing the required js files on master page and this is the code that i am using in my ready function.

```
 $(document).ready(function(){
  $('#grdSummary').tableDnD();
 });
```

The js and Css link are as:

```
   <script src="Scripts/jquery-1.5.1.min.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
    <link href="Styles/tablednd.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />
    <script src="Scripts/jquery.tablednd.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
```

I went through the documentation, It says you just have to use the tableDnD function to get the job done , Am i missing something here. Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure but can you try as below

```
    $(document).ready(function(){
      $('#<%=grdSummary.ClientID%>').tableDnD();
      });
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: Already tried that, doesnt make any difference. Instead of using the clientID attribute we can make use of the css class. Its much more easy but here i am referring through the ID

Comment: More information is needed for looking into this. can you please post grid markup

Answer (score 0):

Try giving id names to all of your TD's, and TR's, as well as the grid.  This will help.
http://www.pedrera.com/blog/asp-net-listview-drag-and-drop-reordering-using-jquery/